# addNetwork not returning -1 if the password is incorrect in android

Tags: java, android

```
int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
```

`addNetwork` is not returning `-1` if the password is incorrect

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

> addNetwork is not returning -1 if the password is incorrect

thats is because wifi login is asynchronous process, and it is not completed once addNetwork finishes. This function is rather checking if parameters were properly set and returns -1 if they are incorrect. You can see what it does here:

http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/src/com/android/managedprovisioning/WifiConfig.java#49

also, I suppose you should enable your configuration, so you code should look as follows:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int netid = wm.addNetwork(wc);
wm.enableNetwork(netid , true);
if (wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
  wm.reconnect();
} else {
  wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
// ...
// now wait for broadcast that connection was made
```

Comment: I want like if the password is incorrect then connect to previous network, what should i do